# using sprintf to round float numbers

Tags: perl

I have the following perl code and want to round the last diget i used sprintf but i get some weird result when the last digest is 5 i expect the rounding to be up but the actual result is different below an example :

```
   my $x = sprintf("%.1f",4.35);    -> expected 4.4
    my $y=     sprintf("%.1f",4.36); -> expected 4.4
    my $z = sprintf("%.1f",4.32);  -> expected 4.3

      print $x,"\n"; -> actual result 4.3 -> expected 4.4
      print $y,"\n"; -> actual result 4.4 -> ok
      print $z,"\n"; -> actual result 4.3 ->ok
```

how can i change the above code /or if there are another option to get the expected results ?

Comment: What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Or see [Bankers Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banker%27s_rounding#Round_half_to_even)

Comment: It's a precision issue: `perl -e 'printf("%.16f\n", 4.35);'`

Comment: @nwellnhof - Yes, you are correct - bankers rounding doesn't apply in this case, only when rounding to an int I think.

Comment: @ChrisCharley On the Ubuntu system I'm currently on, printf does use bankers' rounding. `perl -e 'printf("%.1f %.1f\n", 1.25, 1.75)'` prints `1.2 1.8`. But this only works for numbers which can be represented exactly.

Comment: @nwellnhof Its funny but, on my windows 7 system, your example prints `1.3 1.8`. Don't know what to make of it?

Comment: @ChrisCharley See [here](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4943) for a discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4.35 would get rounded to 4.4, but you actually have something slightly less than 4.35.

---

35/100 is periodic in binary just like 1/3 is periodic in decimal.

```
$ perl -E'say sprintf "%.20g", 0.35'
0.34999999999999998
```

Of course, the same applies to 4 35/100.

```
$ perl -E'say sprintf "%.20g", 4.35'
4.3499999999999996
```

As such, 0.35 and 4.35 cannot be represented exactly using a floating point number.

---

The following solution relies on the fact that 0.5 isn't periodic in binary (0.5 = 1/2 = 2<sup>-1</sup>, a finite sum of powers of 2):

```
$ perl -E'
   say sprintf("%.0f", sprintf("%.15g", $_ * 10)) / 10
      for 4.35, 4.36, 4.32;
'
4.4
4.4
4.3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
% perl -E 'printf("%.1f\n", $_) for ( 4.35, 4.350000001 )'
4.3
4.4
```

`4.35` is actually `4.34999999999999999`

A kludge might be:

```
% perl -E 'printf("%.1f\n", $_ + 1e-15) for ( 4.35, 4.350000001 )'
4.4
4.4
```

Comment: ok there are any other option to get my expected results ?if 4.35 to round up if less than 5 to round down

Answer (score 0):

The best way is not to use floating point, but multiply all by 10 here; especially if money is involved.

For imprecise calculations, one may just accept that 4.35 actually is 4.349999.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Math::Round](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3a%3aRound) module to see if works for your needs.

```
use Math::Round qw( nlowmult nhimult );

print nhimult(.1, 4.35), "\n";    # 4.4
print nhimult(.1, 4.45), "\n";    # 4.5

print nlowmult(.1, 4.35), "\n";   # 4.3
print nlowmult(.1, 4.45), "\n";   # 4.4
```

Comment: `sprintf` provides banker's rounding (round half to even), so neither of those two functions would provide the same functionality.